# How to reach from Terminal 3 to Terminal 2 in Dubai airport

Tags: transit-visas, airport-terminals, armenian-citizens

Good day.

I am going to take a trip from Sydney (SYD) to Yerevan (EVN) via Dubai (DXB). The first part of the flight is with Emirates (EK), the second part with Fly Dubai (FZ). In Dubai airport I should change terminals between 3 to 2. I would like to know how I can reach Terminal 2 from Terminal 3. And do I need a visa if I am not going to leave the airport?

Comment: For the visa question: is the trip in a single booking?

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to leave the airport. You just need to follow the transit sign and that will lead you to transfer desk area where they will help you to move from T3 to T2 using the airside road.

Answer (score 2):

I was exactly in the same situation some years ago, arriving from SYD.

If you're not going to leave the airport, you don't need any visa. Inside the airport, directions are well indicated (in Arabic and in English), and you just have to follow the signs.

Be careful, the airport is huge and you'll need about 20 minutes to go from T3 to T2 at a reasonable pace.